# AWS Api Gateway + Lambda integration + Lambda authorizer -> how to keep refresh token between user and authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, aws-api-gateway, refresh-token

According to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.5 refresh token should be kept between client and authorizer.

Question is: how to achieve it with our setup, which is like in the illustration here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

We've just added refresh token to JWT, lambda authorizer calls another service to check and refresh JWT and refresh token and returns them in set-cookie headers. Then they are passed with the request to the called Lambda (passing refresh token to it is wrong) and lambda adds these set-cookie headers to it's response to user.

So: is there a way to avoid passing refresh token to called Lambda but somehow add it to the response?

Answer (score -1):

Answering myself: it is possible.
Described here: https://supertokens.com/docs/thirdpartyemailpassword/serverless/with-aws-lambda/authorizer
how to set set-cookie headers from authorizer response context.

Using mapping templates it is possible to strip down refresh token from the request to the resource.